# socket.on not working in client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, vue.js

I'm studying nodejs + vuejs + socket.io
Testing sending message and reciving on server side and client side.

**On server side is working, I'm recieving the console(message: text)**
But, the `console.log` on the client side is not working. Nothing appears.

index.html:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<body>
     <div class="container" id="todo">
      <h1><%= title %></h1>
      <h3>{{subtitle}}</h3>
      <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
      <div id="app-5">
       <p>{{ subtitle }}</p>
       <button v-on:click="sendMessage">Send Message</button>
      </div>
     </div>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/app.js"></script>
```

app.js:

```
var socket = io();

var vm = new Vue({
 el: '#todo',
  data: {
   subtitle: 'Hello Vue.js!',
   text: 'Hello Friends',
   menssages: []
 },
 methods: {
  sendMessage: function () {
   socket.emit('chat message', this.text);
  }
}
});

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
 console.log('Client side message: ' + msg)
});
```

nodejs server:

```
io.on( "connection", function( socket ) {
console.log( "A user connected" );

socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  console.log('messagem: ' + msg);
});
});
```

I'm recieving the message on terminal server. But not recieving the `console.log('Client side message: ' + msg)` on the browser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is mainly a socket.io question. You are emitting an event from the client:

```
socket.emit('chat message', this.text);
```

and then listening on that event on the server:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
  console.log('messagem: ' + msg);
});
```

which makes sense and, as you say yourself, works fine: the message gets logged on the server.

However, listening on the `chat message` event on the client:

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
 console.log('Client side message: ' + msg)
});
```

does not work until ***the server*** has emitted this event.

In other words, try executing:

```
socket.emit('chat message', 'Hello World.');
```

***on the server*** to see `Hello World` logged on the client.

Comment: Thank you sir. This `socket.emit`is inside the `socket.on('chat message'...` ?

Comment: If you want it to.

Comment: Could you explain why here @RashadSaleh? ```does not work until the server has emitted this event.```